# I'm Working with liveblocks in my next application. While creating rooms in my components I'm getting an error

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Server Error
TypeError: (0 , *liveblocks_react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_.default) is not a function

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
liveblocks.config.ts (85:78) @ client

83 |   useRemoveReaction,
84 | }

> 85 | } = createRoomContext<Presence, Storage, UserMeta, RoomEvent, ThreadMetadata>(client, {
> |                                                                            ^
> 86 | async resolveUsers({ userIds }) {
> 87 |   // Used only for Comments. Return a list of user information retrieved
> 88 |   // from `userIds`. This info is used in comments, mentions etc.

Code for room.tsx

```
import  {ReactNode} from 'react';
import  {ClientSideSuspense} from '@liveblocks/react'

import  {RoomProvider}  from '@/liveblocks.config';

interface RoomProps { 
  children: ReactNode
  roomId: string;
  fallback: NonNullable<ReactNode> | null;
};
const Room = ({ 
  children,
  roomId,
  fallback,
}: RoomProps) => {
  return (
    <RoomProvider 
    id={roomId} 
    initialPresence={
      {}
    }
    // initialStorage={{
    //   layers: new LiveMap<string, LiveObject<Layer>>(),
    //   layerIds: new LiveList(),
    // }}
  >
    <ClientSideSuspense fallback={fallback}>
      {() => children}
    </ClientSideSuspense>
  </RoomProvider>
    )
}


export default Room
```

code for page.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import Canvas from  './_components/canvas'
import Room from '@/components/room';
import SimpleLoader from '@/components/Loaders/simple-loader';

interface BoardIdPageProps {
    params: {
      boardId: string;
    };
  };
  
  const BoardIdPage = ({
    params,
  }: BoardIdPageProps) => {  
  return (
    <main
      className="h-full w-full relative bg-neutral-100 touch-none"
    >
      <Room roomId={params.boardId} fallback={<SimpleLoader />}> 
        <Canvas boardId={params.boardId} />
      </Room>
        
    </main>
  )
}

export default BoardIdPage
```

code for liveblock.config.ts

```
import { createClient } from "@liveblocks/client";
import { createRoomContext } from "@liveblocks/react";
  
const client = createClient({
  publicApiKey: "pk_dev_Mlm5l54BhELjDRrhRrvlbBAih9GS5wCPSTLaXLeBXZpiDI7Cw_BCNyURhNuTEtvt",  
});

// Presence represents the properties that exist on every user in the Room
// and that will automatically be kept in sync. Accessible through the
// `user.presence` property. Must be JSON-serializable.
type Presence = {
  // cursor: { x: number, y: number } | null,
  // ...
};

// Optionally, Storage represents the shared document that persists in the
// Room, even after all users leave. Fields under Storage typically are
// LiveList, LiveMap, LiveObject instances, for which updates are
// automatically persisted and synced to all connected clients.
type Storage = {
  // author: LiveObject<{ firstName: string, lastName: string }>,
  // ...
};

// Optionally, UserMeta represents static/readonly metadata on each user, as
// provided by your own custom auth back end (if used). Useful for data that
// will not change during a session, like a user's name or avatar.
type UserMeta = {
  // id?: string,  // Accessible through `user.id`
  // info?: Json,  // Accessible through `user.info`
};

// Optionally, the type of custom events broadcast and listened to in this
// room. Use a union for multiple events. Must be JSON-serializable.
type RoomEvent = {
  // type: "NOTIFICATION",
  // ...
};

// Optionally, when using Comments, ThreadMetadata represents metadata on
// each thread. Can only contain booleans, strings, and numbers.
export type ThreadMetadata = {
  // resolved: boolean;
  // quote: string;
  // time: number;
};

export const {
  suspense: {
    RoomProvider,
    useRoom,
    useMyPresence,
    useUpdateMyPresence,
    useSelf,
    useOthers,
    useOthersMapped,
    useOthersConnectionIds,
    useOther,
    useBroadcastEvent,
    useEventListener,
    useErrorListener,
    useStorage,
    useObject,
    useMap,
    useList,
    useBatch,
    useHistory,
    useUndo,
    useRedo,
    useCanUndo,
    useCanRedo,
    useMutation,
    useStatus,
    useLostConnectionListener,
    useThreads,
    useUser,
    useCreateThread,
    useEditThreadMetadata,
    useCreateComment,
    useEditComment,
    useDeleteComment,
    useAddReaction,
    useRemoveReaction,
  }
} = createRoomContext<Presence, Storage, UserMeta, RoomEvent, ThreadMetadata>(client, {
  async resolveUsers({ userIds }) {
    // Used only for Comments. Return a list of user information retrieved
    // from `userIds`. This info is used in comments, mentions etc.
    
    // const usersData = await __fetchUsersFromDB__(userIds);
    // 
    // return usersData.map((userData) => ({
    //   name: userData.name,
    //   avatar: userData.avatar.src,
    // }));
    
    return [];
  },
  async resolveMentionSuggestions({ text, roomId }) {
    // Used only for Comments. Return a list of userIds that match `text`.
    // These userIds are used to create a mention list when typing in the
    // composer. 
    //
    // For example when you type "@jo", `text` will be `"jo"`, and 
    // you should to return an array with John and Joanna's userIds:
    // ["john@example.com", "joanna@example.com"]
    
    // const userIds = await __fetchAllUserIdsFromDB__(roomId);
    //
    // Return all userIds if no `text`
    // if (!text) {
    //   return userIds;
    // }
    //
    // Otherwise, filter userIds for the search `text` and return
    // return userIds.filter((userId) => 
    //   userId.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase())  
    // );
    
    return [];
  },
});
```